What is the definition of a differential equation's general solution?
I'm not an English speaker.
Sorry for my bad English.

What is the definition of a differential equation's general solution?

Definitions I've heard are

"a solution containing arbitrary constants" or "a solution containing as many arbitrary constants as the order of the equation"

But I don't think these are general definitions.
For example, can these be called general solutions?
$$x\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=2\frac{dy}{dx}$$
$$y=
\begin{cases}
c_1x^3 & (x\geq0) \\
c_2x^3 & (x<0)
\end{cases}$$
$$y=x^3+f(c_1,c_2) \qquad (c_1,c_2:\text{constant}, f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}:\text{bijection})$$
What is the definition of the general solution, particular solution, and singular solution of a differential equation?
Addendum:
Consider the following equation
$y=x\frac{dy}{dx}+(\frac{dy}{dx})^2$
The general solution to this equation is $y=cx+c^2$.
The singular solution is $y=-\frac{1}{4}x^2$.
However, it can be expressed like this, combining general solution & singular solution
$$y=\pi_1(f(c))x^2+\pi_2(f(c))x+{\pi_2(f(c))}^2$$
where, f is defined as follows
$f(c)=\begin{cases}
(-\frac{1}{4}, 0) & (c=0) \\
(0, c) & (c \notin \mathbb{N}_{\geq0}) \\
(0, c-1) & (c \in \mathbb{N}_{>0})
\end{cases}$
Is there any definition that shows that this is not a general solution?

I answer "no" to your examples.  If the DE involves $dy/dx$, then the solution should be differentiable (and therefore continuous).  The "general solution" is $y=Ax^3+B$.

In these examples y is differentiable with x.

Maybe start with the appropriate Shaum’s outline.

I like the way you combined the Solutions !
There are ways to combine 2 (or more) Constants into one , though that is not Simple Constant , In other words , I think Constants should be Simple Constants , not functions of Constants.
Making "general solution" , "particular solution" , and "singular solution" are ways to handle the Solutions , not rigorously classify them.
We should treat Constants as Degrees of freedom :
Eg $1^{st}$ Order ODE has $1$ Degree of freedom , commonly referred to as $1$ Constant.
$2^{nd}$ Order ODE has $2$ Degrees of freedom , commonly referred to as $2$ Constants.
$3^{rd}$ Order ODE has $3$ Degrees of freedom , commonly referred to as $3$ Constants.
In this view , it is immaterial how we combine the Solutions & Constants with functions : Degrees of freedom is unchanged
Eg $y=ax+bx^2+(a+b)$ will have $2$ Degrees of freedom , even when we write it like $y=ax+(b-a)x^2+b$ or $y=(a+b)x+(a-b)x^2+2a$ or ...
When we give Criteria like $y(2)=1$ or $y'(-1)=0$ or $y'(0)=y(-1)$ or $y''(1)=2$ (eg) , we are using $1$ Degree of freedom for each.
We can give $n$ Criteria for ODE of Order $n$.

Thank you for your answer.
Is there a definition for degrees of freedom?
Also, the general solution for $y\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=(\frac{dy}{dx})^2$ is $y=c_1e^{c_2x}$, and the particular solution that satisfies $y(0)=0$ is $y=0$.
What are these degrees of freedom?

(1) Definition is very abstract & a large topic covering various nuances , check [[ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degrees_of_freedom ]] "Degrees of freedom of a system is the number of parameters of the system that may vary independently" , while in common usage the Bolded Part is left out & we get something approximately like "Degrees of freedom of the ODE is the number of parameters of the ODE" which will make the confusion you raised here. (2) Your ODE can have the Criteria $y(0)=1$ (which will fix $c_1$) & the Criteria $y(1)=2$ (which will fix $c_2$) hence it has 2 Degrees of freedom.

An ODE, to be "ordinary", has a domain, an open set in the time-state space, that contains no singular points for the DE. Inside the domain the derivative can be expressed as a continuous function of time and state. This means that singularities are points where this function is not continuous or the solution of a given implicit DE is not possible.
In your first case, solving for $y''(x)$ is not possible at $x=0$. This gives two disjoint components of the domain left and right of the y-axis. In each part there is a general solution. That the so parametrized functions fit together at the origin is not part of ODE theory.
In the second case you can resolve the equation for $y'(x)$ in a locally unique way as continuous function $(x,y)$ as long as the quadratic equation has two different real roots. This gives two ODE with this set as domain, and thus two general solutions that cross in each point. The boundary curve
$$
(2y'+x)^2 = 4y+x^2\implies y(x)=-\frac{x^2}4
$$
has the property of also satisfying the DE, which is a feature typical for Clairaut equations. But strictly speaking this curve or singular solution or envelope does not lie inside the domain of the associated ODEs.

Thank you for your answer.
Does this mean that we should consider the coefficients of $\frac{d^n y}{dx^n}$ separately for each interval that is not 0? (n is the order of the ODE.)
What happens if $y\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=(\frac{dy}{dx})^2$?

Yes, the leading coefficient becoming zero in a linear DE is a point of singularity. In your example, while $y=0$ solves the equation, it is outside the domain as ODE. In a task it would depend on formulation and the exact definitions of the course if the zero function would belong to an answer.
